# ionic 3 custom back button not working

Tags: ionic3

Hi I made a news page which shows the list of news from WordPress Blog. I want to show a back button or arrow on the header of this news page. I have done following steps but getting error 
"Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page" my news.html and news.ts codes are below

News.html

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <button (click)="goBack()">
          <ion-icon name="arrow-back">  </ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>news</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

News.ts  code with goBack() FUNCTION is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WpapiProvider } from '../../providers/wpapi/wpapi';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news',
  templateUrl: 'news.html',
  providers: [WpapiProvider]
})
export class NewsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public api: WpapiProvider) {
    this.api.getPosts();
  }
  goBack() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
   }
}
```

Comment: rootPage as an error is probably unrelated can you update your description to show the full error as you see it.  If you are using the blank template as starting the app.html should have rootPage like `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>` and your app.component.ts should define the root page like `rootPage:any = HomePage;`

Comment: Thanks Philip. Its done. When I pushed towards the new page with data , an automatic go back appeared.Thanks